# Clustering using the BIRCH algorithm

Tags: clustering

I am trying to solve this question:

Build a CF-tree for the subset of points, (3,3) (4,3) (6,3) (7,4) (7,5)
assuming that the branching factor, B, is set to 2, the maximum number of sub-clusters at each
leaf node, L, is set to 2 and the threshold on the diameter of sub-clusters stored in the leaf nodes is 1.5.

I have googled throughly but aside from what seem to be the same set of slides giving me dry dusty definitions (plagiarised thousands of times at different universities) I have not found a single example (with real numbers) that show me how to actually do the algorithm by hand.

Could someone either tell me how to perform the algorithm (and construct the tree) or point me somewhere that gives examples?

Thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can find some implementations, for example

http://roberto.perdisci.com/projects/jbirch

Which should allow you to exactly follow what is going on, step by step.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that you can find a spoon-fed numerical example of the BIRCH algo. Perhaps you could read the inventors' original papers (easily found by googling) in conjunction with [this](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=birch%20clustering%20example&source=web&cd=14&ved=0CGUQFjADOAo&url=http://csie.org/~dm/clustering.1.1107.ppt&ei=Gqy0T9CKBY2K4gT_nd2jDg&usg=AFQjCNH7Kxp0apq3zODBrpIkiOvcfAlEqQ) illustrative document.

Answer (score 0):

The following presentation help to understand step by step

http://www.inf.unibz.it/dis/teaching/DWDM/slides2010/lesson9-Clustering.pdf

Comment: Hi @Mubarak Abdulla, welcome to the site. As is I think your answer is better as a comment. For it to be an answer you may want to walk through the process with the information given in the question.